# linux: refreshing groups without having to re-login

Tags: linux, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way in Linux to update the user/group properties without having to login again?](https://superuser.com/questions/122744/is-there-a-way-in-linux-to-update-the-user-group-properties-without-having-to-lo)

How does one refresh the groups that a logged-in user is in without having to re-login?

Comment: fyi. the answer marked correct is wrong... and it's still technically a relogin. I added a correct answer... I find that the answer given to this question is usually wrong. it is a common fallacy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

possible in shell (I don't think it is for gui)

try `newgrp groupname`

I wrote more info on this on [my blog](http://xenoterracide.blogspot.com/2009/08/adding-new-group-to-open-shell-without.html) a while back. according to that this will also change the default group of the shell. you can use `sg` to Switch your default Group

Comment: this is essentially no different that doing `su - username` as ignacio pointed out. a new shell process gets loaded and layered on top of the old one. however, you are still technically correct :)

Comment: Prefix with `exec` (`exec newgrp groupname`) if you don't want to have an old shell process laying around.

Comment: @orlandu63 except su changes your user and the -  means change your whole env too. It also can mean you have to login. newgrp doesn't.

@grawity I didn't know that. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 10):

`su - username` will do it for the shell (and subproccesses) that su opens up, but for everything else you'll need to relog.

Comment: this answer is incorrect especially since su is re-logging in. use `newgrp` in an open shell session to add groups to that session, that you've been added to.