# Linux permissions, mv is denied

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I have the following structure (property is in the form user:group, user A belongs to both groups A and B, user B is just in the B group) :

```
+ dir1           rwxrwxr-x     A:A
+ dir2           rwxrwxr-x     A:B
  - file1        rw-rw-r--     B:B
  + dir3         rwxrwxr-x     B:B
    -file2       rw-rw-r--     B:B
```

I (as user A) want to move `file2` to `dir1`. When I do so, I get a "Permisson denied" error (while moving `file1` to `dir1` is working fine). As a result `file2` is copied in `dir1` but still remains in `dir3` as if the group write permission was ignored for the suppression.

What is the problem here?

**EDIT:**

Maybe there's a problem with the group assignation, here's the result of a few commands:

```
$ whoami
A
$ groups
A                   <-- ??? why
$ groups A
A : A B
```

Moreover, the `mv` I'm trying to do is in a script called by a crontab job, and it's working frmo there. Is there something to do to "refresh" groups assignments?

Comment: When you try to move the file **out of folder 3 which is owned by B:B** then you write to that folder. As I read the question you do not have permission to do that. (Making a copy which only reads file2 and then writes it to your directory (dir2) should work. But mv and deleting dir3/file2 should fail).

Comment: Let met rephrase then: Deleting a file from dir3 is allowed to user B and group B (775), since user A is in group B, why is it not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently you have to logout for the changes to take effect, [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out) explains how to bypass the logout if needed.