# How solve permission problems for docker in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, docker

I have installed docker as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-trusty-1404-lts-64-bit). I use [Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 (LTS) (64-bit)](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-trusty-1404-lts-64-bit). Everything during installation was well. Also command `$ sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash` completes well (after I typed "exit" in opened console. But when I tryin to do something else I get "permission denied". For example:

```
`$ sudo docker run -d -P training/webapp python app.py`
```

Reuslts in `Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.12/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied`

```
` docker info`
```

Reuslts in `Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.12/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied`

How to solve this? I googled about the problem but I can not find a solution for my case.

Answer (score 57):

Add the docker group if it doesn't already exist.

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
```

Add the connected user `${USER}` to the docker group. Change the user name to match your preferred user.

```
$ sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
```

Restart the Docker daemon:

```
$ sudo service docker restart # Or docker.io for older versions
# 18.04+ with snap:
$ sudo systemctl restart snap.docker.dockerd
```

You should log out and log in again to update group permissions. To avoid  that, you can switch to a subshell as follows. Or use any of the other tricks mentioned in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out#354475):

```
su - $USER
```

Comment: I had to reboot to get this to take effect.

Comment: Don't have to reboot, just logout and login.

Comment: Logout did it, even when `exec $SHELL` did not. I'm interested to know by which mechanism logging out resolved the issue. This isn't windows!

Comment: In Fedora, first you must edit `/etc/selinux/config` and put `SELINUX=disabled`, then reboot Linux

Comment: You can also run `newgrp docker $USER` to enter the newly added group without having to restart a new session, though this is usually a more temporary solution if you have lots of things going on.

Comment: Great explanation! You're the best! :)

Comment: Why can't they just get it fixed now in 2022? It's a joke...

Answer (score 5):

If you're running CentOS or RedHat, you might have to disable SELinux first by running:

```
setenforce 0
```

Eiter restart afterwards to reenable SELinux or run `setenforce 1`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, due to selinux. You can check if selinux is the culprit by:

1. Disabling selinux: `setenforce 0`
2. Retrying

If disabling selinux solved your problem, it's not a reason to leave it disabled:

1. Enable selinux: `setenforce 1`
2. Allow the socket connection in the selinux configuration: `setsebool docker_connect_any true`
3. Run your Docker container with the `--priviledged` option

Answer (score 3):

I assume, your username is already in docker group. To check this, issue below command.

```
id -nG
```

If not you need to add your user into the docker group by below command.

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

When you execute the command, `sudo systemctl start docker`, it creates a docker process. That docker process contains `dockerd` daemon thread. The command also creates default `docker.sock` Unix socket. The `docker.sock` socket is continuously listened by `dockerd` daemon thread. This makes you can do kernel-level IPC with `docker.pid` process. To be able to use this docker socket, you need to have proper permission from the process level (`docker.pid`) and file level (`docker.sock`). So, executing below two commands should solve your issue. 

`sudo chmod a+rwx /var/run/docker.sock # You can provide just execute permission
sudo chmod a+rwx /var/run/docker.pid`

Answer (score 1):

By [current version](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) we do not need add the group `docker`.
It is exist automatically by the installation. You may check using the command:

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
groupadd: group 'docker' already exists
```

So in order to *[manage Docker as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)*, just add your user to the docker group then log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
$ logout
```

To check it when you log back in

```
$ docker run hello-world
Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

You may even force to use `GROUP:docker` as your new primary group:

```
$ sudo chown "$USER":"docker" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R
$ sudo chmod g+rwx "$HOME/.docker" -R
$ sudo usermod -g docker ${USER}
$ logout
```

To check it when you log back in

```
$ id
uid=1001(<user_name>) gid=999(docker) groups=999(docker),...
```