# Clean solution to apply *unix groups without logging out and in again or hacks

Tags: linux, unix, shell

Regarding [this](https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out) issue. Why I cannot simply reload my (id) groups, with some special command, after changing (adding/removing/etc) groups? Why there is a need to log out and log in again or creating another shell (e.g.: `su - $USER` or `exec su - $USER`)? Is there any "proper" solution to avoid logging out and in again or using nasty hacks? Why is that "system" cannot reload groups/make new assignment (with current shell) without all above hassle?

Comment: Does just running `bash` work to "reset" things in a terminal, since you're now in the "new bash"?